# ClassNotFoundException only on Mac OS

Tags: java, macos, maven, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I'm trying to run a Java project on Intellij 14 Ultimate, with Maven dependencies. Running the project on Windows and Linux doesn't give the error, but running the project on Mac does.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: project.package.LocalServer
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:260)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:116)
```

Why does this error only happen on Mac? All of my config settings for both IntelliJ and the project are the same on every platform.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You use uberjar or lib folder with Classpath in manifest? If classpath -- check for HFS+ case sensitivity mode and classpath entries. Windows has no sensitivity at all, Linux has one always, for Mac it can be switched per volume.

Comment: @Nikolay Thanks for your comment. I'm using IntelliJ so that shouldn't be that problem. :/ Any other suggestions?